connect EMR to s3 interface endpoint during bootstrap
Looking for a solution that helps to connect s3 interface endpoint instead of Gateway endpoint. By default the traffic is flowing through Gateway endpoint during the bootstrap. I have tried adding EMR config as below to the cluster, that didn't help .
Any other possibility or suggestions that could solve the issue to make the connection happen to Interface endpoint and not Gateway endpoint.
[
  {
    "Classification": "core-site",
    "Properties": {
      "fs.s3a.endpoint": "https://vpce-1234567890.s3.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "emrfs-site",
    "Properties": {
      "fs.s3a.endpoint": "https://vpce-1234567890.s3.us-west-2.vpce.amazonaws.com"
    }
  }
]

Note: We need to keep both Interface and Gateway endpoint . Cannot delete the Gateway endpoint as its a mandatory for other requirement.
